# Regex para pegar arquivos com determinados caracteres no nome

Tags: python, regex

Fiquei encarregado num projeto de criar um código que navegue nas pastas do servidor procurando arquivos com nomenclatura errada (Acentos, espaços, pontuação e caracteres especiais..) sendo que eu travei na lógica do regex e não consegui progredir por conta que todos os arquivos tem uma extensão ex:
.txt, .pdf, .doc dentre outros.

E esse bendito ponto faz com que meu código simplismente fique naquele ditato "Ou é 8 ou 80" pois no regex a expressão `\W` captura todos os outros caracteres que eu quero (todos não-alfanumérico) porém como o "." vem junto nessa captura, arquivos que tem a nomenclatura correta como por exemplo: arquivo.txt são acusados como arquivos com nomenclatura errada por conta do bendito ponto.

Segue o código:

```
import os, re;

def encontraArquivosEmPastaRecursivamente(pasta):
 arquivosTxt = []
 caminhoAbsoluto = os.path.abspath(pasta)
 for pastaAtual, subPastas, arquivos  in os.walk(caminhoAbsoluto):
     arquivosTxt.extend([os.path.join(pastaAtual,arquivo)
                         for arquivo in arquivos
                         if(re.findall(r'[áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ\s\W]', arquivo))])

 arquivo = open('lista_de_arquivo.txt', 'w')
 for arquivosTxt in arquivosTxt:
     arquivo.write(arquivosTxt + '\n')
 arquivo.close()

encontraArquivosEmPastaRecursivamente('c:/Users/paulo/Desktop/Ambiente_de_arquivos')
```

Nomes de arquivos que devem estar no arquivo "lista_de_arquivo.txt" após o código rodar:

arquivo 1.txt (arquivo com espaços);

arquivo1!@#$%¨&()_+`´{[ª^~}]º,.;-.txt (arquivo com caracteres especiais);

árquivo 1.txt (arquivo com acentos);

Por sua vez, o que não deve estar na lista:

arquivo4.txt (arquivo sem espaço, sem acento e sem caractere especial)
(porém ele aparece na lista por conta do ".")

Esse é meu ambiente de testes:

[image: Essas são as pastas que o código verifica]

Ignore "pasta1" e "pasta2" são apenas para testar a recursividade do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de fazer uma regex que pega o que quer, você pode optar por pegar o que não quer:

```
r = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$')
arquivosTxt = []
caminhoAbsoluto = os.path.abspath(pasta)
for pastaAtual, subPastas, arquivos  in os.walk(caminhoAbsoluto):
    arquivosTxt.extend([arquivo for arquivo in arquivos if not r.match(arquivo) ])
```

Ou seja, eu não quero um arquivo que só tenha letras não acentuadas e números (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), seguida opcionalmente por uma extensão (`\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - ponto seguido de uma ou mais letras ou números) - o `?` logo depois torna a extensão [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` indicam o início e fim da string, garantindo que vou verificar todo o nome do arquivo.

Depois, é só buscar por aqueles que não satisfazem à expressão (`if not r.match`). Se o nome do arquivo tiver qualquer coisa diferente de letras não acentuadas e números (além da extensão), será incluído na lista.

Comment: Era exatamente essa lógica que eu não consegui pensar, sou muito novo no Regex, Muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!